# Will an instance be garbage collected if a Task's callback get reference to the instance itself?

Tags: c#, multithreading, async-await, garbage-collection

```
public class Cls
{
    public object Obj { get; set; }

    public async void Func()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Thread.Sleep(999999999);
            this.Obj = new { };
        });
    }
}

public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Cls().Func();
    }
}
```

Please consider the above codes and neglect if it makes sense first. In the above case, I did not store instance of `Cls` into any variable, seems that nothing is referencing that instance and it would be GC. However, there is a `Task.Run()` in side `Func`. The callback function of the `Task` make a reference to the instance's `Obj` property. May I will it still be collected by GC in such case?

---

I am asking this question because in Microsoft [doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/signalr/hubs?view=aspnetcore-3.1#create-and-use-hubs) of SignalR it stated

> Use await when calling asynchronous methods that depend on the hub staying alive.

I don't understand how come the `Hub` will not still alive as long as something inside `Clients.All.SendAsync` is referencing to the `Hub` itself...

Thanks.

Comment: Which callback?

Comment: Your program ends first, also no `Cls` will not be garbage collected while the task is alive. Just the fact your are calling `this` prevents it, among other things...

Comment: @Gusman the lambda function inside Task.Run

Comment: For every method call SignalR creates a new instance of the `Hub` class. After that method call is over SignalR will `Dispose` that `Hub` instance. So if you don't `await` an `async` call it will only start it and not wait for completion, then call `Dispose` on the `Hub` instance. This `Dispose` is directly called from the SignalR framework so has nothing to do with GarbageCollection and having references to a `Hub`.

Comment: So the answer to your question is "No it will not be collected by the GC if there is an active reference to the `Hub`, however it will have been disposed and therefor not 'alive' anymore"

Comment: OHHHHHH...  I see...   the meaning of "alive" is before "dispose"!!!   Thank you @Knoop

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, it will not be garbage collected, because you have reference to `this` in `Task.Run()` (even if you reference `this` before call to `Thead.Sleep()`).

However, if you're running this code in Azure Functions, for example, the framework may terminate your app instance and the code in callback will not ever run (not because of being garbage collected).

By the way, you can manually check if it is garbage collected by calling `GC.Collect()`, which performs garbage collection.

You can use this code to test it (run it in C# Interactive, for example)

```
static async Task Main(string[] args)
{
    static void CreateObjectAndCallFunc()
    {
        var clsInstance = new Cls();
        clsInstance.Func();
    }

    CreateObjectAndCallFunc();

    Console.WriteLine($"before Task.Delay");
    await Task.Delay(10);
    Console.WriteLine($"after Task.Delay");

    Console.WriteLine($"GC.Collect()");
    GC.Collect();
    Console.WriteLine($"after GC.Collect()");

    Console.WriteLine($"before Task.Delay");
    await Task.Delay(10);
    Console.WriteLine($"after Task.Delay");
}

public class Cls
{
    public Cls() { Console.WriteLine("Cls constructor"); }
    ~Cls() { Console.WriteLine("!!! Cls deconstructor"); }

    public object Obj { get; set; }

    public void Func()
    {
        Task.Run(() =>
        {
            System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(99999);
            this.Obj = new object();
        });
    }
}
await Main(null);
```

If you don't reference `this.Obj` in Task.Run(..), then it will output this:

```
Cls constructor
before Task.Delay
after Task.Delay
GC.Collect()
after GC.Collect()
before Task.Delay
!!! Cls deconstructor
after Task.Delay
```

but if you do, it will output this:

```
Cls constructor
before Task.Delay
after Task.Delay
GC.Collect()
after GC.Collect()
before Task.Delay
after Task.Delay
```

Comment: thank you. I will mark it as accepted answer later on. Because I still don't understand how is the `Hub` in SignalR works.   Seems that if I don't `await` the `Task`, the callback inside the `Task` cannot get reference to the instance as it is garbage collected.

Comment: I'm not familiar with SignalR, but maybe it's similar to how Azure Functions work. If you await a Task, the framework knows that you need the app instance to hold and won't terminate. You need to investigate that, I don't know

Comment: Thank you @Artemious   so clear   I will take a try!!